# What file types does HTTP cache?

Tags: http, caching

I am aware that HTTP caching stores files on the client to reduce requests to the server. I assume that HTTP caches any and all HTTP responses it receives, **regardless of file type.** That would mean it caches .html, .css, .js, .png, .jpeg, .txt, .php, .mvc, .asp, .flv, .etc, and every other file type imaginable.

Comment: @SLaks Thank you. Why did you answer this in a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: That's a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assume correctly.

HTTP has no intrinsic notion of types.